# How to show seconds in Windows 10 taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

When I need to know the seconds in Windows 10, I need to click on the clock to open it, but that is annoying if I need to do it multiple times or I need to wait for the next minute to be reached.

I would like the taskbar clock to have the seconds (HH:MM:SS) instead of only hours and minutes (HH:MM).

Comment: In an old version of Windows (possibly 95), MS discovered that updating the taskbar clock with seconds used a high amount of CPU.  They took it out for performance reasons originally.  Not a big problem nowadays.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/325096/how-to-make-windows-10s-taskbar-clock-display-seconds/) and is really simple:

1. Open the Registry Editor by typing **regedit** in the start menu
2. Navigate to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
3. Right-click in the **Advanced** key in the left pane, go to **New** and then click in **DWORD (32-bit) Value**.
4. Name the value **ShowSecondsInSystemClock** and press Enter.
5. Double-click the value you just created in the right pane, enter a value of **1** and click **OK** (You can leave it Hexadecimal).
6. Sign out or restart the computer.

Comment: You can restart Windows explorer using Task Manager instead of restarting PC.

Comment: Hey Edu, can you update your answer to include @VadimOvchinnikov 's suggestion. It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to enable seconds by using [this method.](https://superuser.com/a/1325200/862301)

#### You can use an open-source software called *T-Clock*.

It also has some useful and handy window management features, so it is a solid toolbox.
http://i1-win.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/T-Clock-Redux_1.png

You can **customize the date/time format** by using *advanced clock format*.

http://i.computer-bild.de/imgs/2/4/8/0/8/1/4/Screenshot-3-T-Clock-Redux-487x439-0c9927541867a725.jpg