# How can I display 'seconds' in Windows 10 Task bar?

Tags: windows-10, clock

It shows only date, hour and miniutes such as 11:41 PM, 8/20/2020.
I would like to see the 'seconds' always on the task bar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show seconds in Windows 10 taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/1325199/how-to-show-seconds-in-windows-10-taskbar)

Comment: there are already lots of duplicates if you've googled for `show second taskbar windows site:superuser.com`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show seconds on the Windows 10 tray clock](https://superuser.com/questions/950283/how-to-show-seconds-on-the-windows-10-tray-clock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Registry Editor.
Win key and searching 'regedit' would show the application.

Go to
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`

Make a new 'DWORD(32bit)' item with the value `ShowSecondsInSystemClock` and set data to 1